# Can I allow my database to be accessed from anywhere if I have "good" credentials?

Tags: security, deployment, devops, digital-ocean

I'm deploying a Node/React app to [DigitalOcean Apps](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/)(similar to Heroku) and a Database to [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas). DigitalOcean do not [provide external fixed IP addresses](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ip-my-digital-ocean-app).

I want to secure the connection between the Server and database. Obviously I can't use the whitelist feature, since my server doesn't have a fixed IP.

My questions are:

1. Can I allow the database to be accessed from anywhere if I put my app to production?
2. What can I do to fix this problem? -how can I secure the connection in my server-database setup?

Comment: Usually we would solve this using mutual authentication in TLS, with i.e. with a client certificate on the DigitalOcean and the DB having server authentication (which is always present for any "normal" TLS connection). Just to give you a direction to a possible answer...